# Different Garbage Collectors in c#

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I got a simple question for which I couldn't find an answer whatsoever.

Now let me first describe why I even think about asking this: I am a student and have been given the task to test different GC's and how they perform and function.

But I couldn't find any other GC besides the standard that is referenced everywhere which is the generational gc.

Now I know there is the "Generational GC" and like on IOS the one that just counts references on objects.

Can you describe to me which types of GC's exist?

Thank you

Comment: I hope I was able to reword the question so it is no more considered off-topic. If it still is considered to be off-topic I will remove it.
I want to mention I never asked for a recommondation but rather for a an objective list or single gc.
-> [Changes] Reworded the question so it does no more include asking for references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many more hours I found a good list of different GC's. These are from a source I'm not allowed to reference. But heres the snippt:

```
Generational (Example: .NET)
Background (Example: .NET)
Reference counting (Example: COM)
Concurrent (Example: Oracle CMS)
Deterministic/real-time (Example: Azul Zing)
Region-based (Example: Oracle G1)
Incremental (Example: Oracle CLP)
```

Comment: I listed GC's that are not only for C# but it gives a good idea whats out there.